# Let $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ and $g(x,y)=\frac{e^{-1}}{x^2+y^2}$. Show that $f(a,b)=g(a,b)$ at any point $(a,b)$ where $a^2+b^2=1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ and $g(x,y)=\frac{e^{-1}}{x^2+y^2}$.

a) Show that $f(a,b)=g(a,b)$ at any point $(a,b)$ where $a^2+b^2=1$.

b) Show that the graph of $f$ is tangent to the graph of $g$ at every point $(a,\ b)$ where $a^2+b^2=1$.

For a),
\begin{align*}
f(a, b)&=g(a, b)\\
e^{-(x^2+y^2)}&=\frac{1}{e(x^2+y^2)}\\
\Rightarrow e(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}&=1 \\
x^2e^{-x^2-y^2+1}+y^2e^{-x^2-y^2+1}&=1
\end{align*}

I don't know how to continue with the calculation.

For b), I do not know if the following is useful: if two functions $f$ and $g$ have the same value $f(a, b)=g(a, b)$ and the same partial derivatives at $(a, b)$, then their tangent planes at $(a, b, f(a, b))$ are equal and we say that the graphs are tangent at that point.

Comment: for a), just plug in $1$ for $x^2+y^2$. what u have written now is incorrect.

Comment: For part (a), I don't understand why the result isn't immediate.  When $(a^2 + b^2) = 1$, then the denominator of $g(a,b) = 1$, and $f(a,b)$ matches the numerator of $g(a,b)$.  Personally, I don't see what else needs to be said for part (a).

Comment: If $(a,b)$ satisfies $a^2+b^2=1$, then $f(a,b) = e^{-(\color{red}{a^2+b^2})} = e^{-\color{red}1}$ while $g(a,b) = \frac{e^{-1}}{\color{red}{a^2+b^2}} = \frac{e^{-1}}{\color{red}1} = e^{-1}$.

Comment: Make $z=x^2+y^2$ and the only solution of $f(z)=g(z)$ is $z=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work for (a) is correct! You just have to apply the condition that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$, and I recommend you do so on the second equality you obtained: $e^{-(a^2 + b^2)} = \frac{1}{e(a^2 + b^2)}$.

To show that the graph of $f$ is tangent to the graph of $g$, you need to compute the tangent plane to $g$ and verify that it matches $f$ at the points $(a, b)$ with $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. Recall that the tangent plane of $g$ at $(a, b)$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
T(a, b) = g(a, b) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(a, b)(x - a) + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(a, b)(y - b).
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

Where $a^2+b^2=1$:  $f(a,b)=e^{-(a^2+b^2)}=e^{-1}$ and $g(a,b)=\frac{e^{-1}}{a^2+b^2}=e^{-1}$

Why did you post this???